# Organizing household objects

Tags: windows, web-apps, database, ios, cross-platform

I want to organize all my things.

The main point here is to organize everything in a hierarchical structure, and this structure needs to be easily, quickly and visually editable via drag and drop. An entire parent and it's children must be seamlessly movable to other positions on another nesting level.

The contents of each object doesn't need to be anything else than text. Pictures is of course a plus, but not by far a requirement. The most important thing here is swiftness.

What I do want, though, is a cross-platform solution. I have an iPhone and an iPad in addition to my Windows desktop computer. Then I can move around my flat and take notes and organize without having to continually return to my computer.

The closest I've come this far is bulleted lists in Google Docs, Sublime Text 3 for using keyboard shortcuts (both for increasing and decreasing tab level and moving item up and down) and Sortly. The last one is way too slow, though, so that is not an alternative.

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: So you want a cloud app, where the iPhone, iPad, and Windows PC all access the same server-based dataset, even simultaneously? Or did you intend to collect data on each device, then move the data into the Windows PC?

Comment: The former, if possible. Google Docs is the closest as of now.